# ASP.Net AJAX form causes Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am new to AJAX and I'm trying to create a very small test just updating a label when pressing a button without reloading the page. The c# method gets called and the label is updated, but the page still seems to reload since the Page_Load is called with IsPostBack=true. What am I missing here? Using Visual Studio 2017.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" enablepartialrendering="true" />
        <div class="main">   
            <div>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlMain" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest" Text="Inte tryckt" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" class="button" Text="Import" OnClick="btnSelectFile_Click" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>


        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior, even for post back made through `UpdatePanel`, `IsPostBack`  will be `true`.

If you want to differentiate the postback you can check like following.

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)         
{          
    // Your code when the request is partially posted back         
}
```